# Why does mypy complain about TextIOWrapper receiving GzipFile as argument 1?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I am writing stuff to an in-memory binary stream in order to upload stuff to S3 without storing it on a local file (I have more memory than disk space). The following code is working, but `mypy mvce.py` fails with

```
mvce.py:6: error: Argument 1 to "TextIOWrapper" has incompatible type "GzipFile";
expected "IO[bytes]"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

### mvce.py

```
from io import BytesIO, TextIOWrapper
import gzip

inmem = BytesIO()
with gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=inmem, mode="wb") as gzip_handler, TextIOWrapper(
    gzip_handler, encoding="utf-8"
) as wrapper:
    wrapper.write("some test string")


# Check if this actually worked
with open("foobar.gzip", "wb") as f1:
    inmem.seek(0)
    f1.write(inmem.read())


with gzip.open("foobar.gzip", "rb") as f2:
    data = f2.read()

print(data)
```

### Question

Why does mypy fail and how do I make it work? Are there hidden potential issues?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Why does MyPy fail?

MyPy uses a set of type stubs called [Typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/) to define types for the standard library.  In Typeshed, `gzip.GzipFile` does not inherit from `typing.IO[bytes]`.

The class hierarchy is: `gzip.GzipFile -> _compression.BaseStream -> io.BufferedIOBase -> io.IOBase`.

### How do I make it work?

You can use `typing.cast(IO[bytes], gzip_handler)` to hint to MyPy that the `GzipFile` instance should be considered a binary file object.  See the [documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/casts.html) for more info about casts.

Alternatively, you could use `gzip.open(inmem, mode='wt', encoding="utf-8")` to get a text file object directly (essentially the same as what you're doing, see below). This function has return type `IO[Any]` in Typeshed.

### Are there hidden potential issues?

The [`gzip` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html) says this about the `gzip.open()` function:

> For text mode, a [`GzipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.GzipFile) object is created, and wrapped in an [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) instance with the specified encoding, error handling behavior, and line ending(s).

So your code should work fine in practice.

### Can this be fixed in Typeshed?

I tried adding `IO[bytes]` as a superclass of `GZipFile` in Typeshed, and I got one error in the tests:

```
stdlib/3/gzip.pyi:17: error: Definition of "__enter__" in base class "IOBase" is incompatible with definition in base class "IO"
```

The solution to this issue is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This has been fixed in typeshed now, see https://github.com/python/typeshed/pull/4146

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think that change addresses this issue. `GzipFile` remains incompatible with `IO[bytes]`.

Comment: I can't honestly remember why I commented here.

Comment: See this https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/6077: typing.IO and io.BaseIO type hierarchies are incompatible